# Using multiple NSTimers on iOS - Only one timer fires

Tags: objective-c, ios, concurrency, nstimer, nsrunloop

Need help with a problem.

**Goal**
I'm putting together an iOS book app that uses NSTimers to fire off several staggered animation events after loading a view.  I've created a *MethodCallerWithTimer* class to help me do this (code at bottom).

**My Solution So Far**
When I use the *MethodCallerWithTimer* class, I assign the objectOwningMethod as my UIViewController subclass object (it's a book page), and then the method as an instance method in that class.  Here is an example of a method I assign - quite simply turning on some artwork on the screen:

```
- (void) playEmory {
   [emoryRedArt setHidden:NO];
}
```

**My Issue**
When I create multiple *MethodCallerWithTimer* instances then load the view and start them all, I only ever get the FIRST event to happen.  None of the other timers call their target methods.  I suspect I don't understand what I'm asking NSRunLoop to do or something similar.

Any thoughts?

Here is my *MethodCallerWithTimer* class:

```
@interface MethodCallerWithTimer : NSObject {
    NSTimer * timer;
    NSInvocation * methodInvocationObject;
    NSNumber * timeLengthInMS;
}

- (id) initWithObject: (id) objectOwningMethod AndMethodToCall: (SEL) method;
- (void) setTime: (int) milliseconds;
- (void) startTimer;
- (void) cancelTimer;

@end
```

And implementation:

```
#import "MethodCallerWithTimer.h"

@implementation MethodCallerWithTimer

- (id) initWithObject: (id) objectOwningMethod AndMethodToCall: (SEL) method {
    NSMethodSignature * methSig = [[objectOwningMethod class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:method];
    methodInvocationObject = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methSig];
    [methodInvocationObject setTarget:objectOwningMethod];
    [methodInvocationObject setSelector:method];
    [methSig release];
    return [super init];
}
- (void) setTime: (int) milliseconds {
    timeLengthInMS = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:milliseconds];
}
- (void) startTimer {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:([timeLengthInMS longValue]*0.001) invocation:methodInvocationObject repeats:NO];
}
- (void) cancelTimer {
    [timer invalidate];
}
-(void) dealloc {
    [timer release];
    [methodInvocationObject release];
    [timeLengthInMS release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These look like one-time firings after a delay; have you considered using something like:

```
[myObject performSelector:@selector(playEmory) withObject:nil afterDelay:myDelay];
```

where `myObject` is the instance with the `playEmory` routine and `myDelay` is a `float` of the seconds you want the OS to wait before making the call?

You can find out more information about this flavor of `performSelector` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a).

Comment: GREAT suggestion, fbrereto.  Thanks. That worked for me.  I'm still kind of curious why my previous implementation didn't, but I should be able to get by with this just fine.